# recovering data from raid1 component disk

Tags: ubuntu, raid, software-raid, data-recovery

Need to recover data from raid1 component disk using ubuntu live usb disk. The existing software raid was broken. After many attempts, I removed degraded raid setup from BIOS but ubuntu live could not detect filesystem on any of the two component disks.

disk utility says "raid component disk" in one of the disks.
gparted does not report filesystem in any disks.

Please suggest.

Comment: You tag this with [tag:software-raid], yet you say you removed the raid from the BIOS. So, what kind of RAID were you really running?

Comment: the one you get in motherboards, also called FakeRAID: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem of data recovery. `fsck` command failed to detect filesystem.
`fsck.ext4` detected the journal with a warning and then went on to fix all nodes. Later was able to mount the disk partition and get the required files.
Was never able to boot from that disk again though but that was ok.

Answer (score 1):

Consider running [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) for recovery purposes. It is part of most recovery live CDs and appears to be [part of Ubuntu Live](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery#Testdisk).

FakeRAID solutions write some metadata to the member disks. If the spec engineers were smart, the metadata is written to the end of the disk to ease recovery. If they were not, the metadata is at the beginning of the disk - where usually the partitioning data would be. A Testdisk scan for partitions and filesystems should be able to find the offset partitions.

Comment: before i read the answer, i had somehow succeeded in running fsck.ext4 to detect the journal on my 1TB disk and its running and dumping numbers in console.